# Boolean Parameter in CPLEX

Tags: cplex

How can I define a boolean parameter in CPLEX Optimization studio? It will be an input to my model and the available type for defining a input is float, string and int.

Comment: There is a `binary` type of variables as well.

Comment: In CPLEX itself there are binary or bool variables. But in OPL there isn't. You only get integers, floats and strings as basic data types. If I am working in OPL, I usually use an integer and follow the convention that 0=false, 1=true

Comment: You are right Tim. I have somehow managed to convert it into an integer. Thanks for your comment though.

Answer (score -1):

boolean parameter in CPLEX is limited for variable declarations. You can only use

dvar boolean variable = ...;

Just use a int instead.